# Angular Material Spinner Not Spinning when parsing a lot of data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am simply trying to use mat-spinner and it works fine even with *ngIf conditions on a loading flag or with an async subject.

```js
// Works fine with a condition that does not involve checking file validation status
<div *ngIf="true" class="loading-shade">
   <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>

// Same here... as long as not check file upload and validation status
<div *ngIf="loadingStream$ | async" class="loading-shade">
   <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

The spinner is used when a file is uploaded and validated. During the validation, there are a lot of checks and iterations. I feel like due to the processing of the data, the spinner does not "animate".

```js
// During Validation === true Just a blue spec on screen
<div *ngIf="isValidating" class="loading-shade">
   <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you have to check when you are setting the value of isValidating

Comment: @FolabiAhn I also use the same variable to disable the upload button during the validation process. The button disables and enables as expected...BUT the spinner...just not working.

Comment: Are you sure the call to your back api is not fast ? Can you please share your code where you are setting isValidating also